# Can't boot into slackware installer

Tags: boot, osx, dual-boot, macintosh, slackware

Can't boot into Slackware installer, I get stuck in this:

[image: mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice]

The last line I see is: `mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice`
I tried a external Keyboard with Mouse (Cordless but at least compatible with my Ubuntu, Mac OS X, and Windows...) and its the same problem...

If you want you can see the boot process [here](https://meocloud.pt/link/613c8f3c-179c-48bc-b464-9e34dd207d9f/slackware-boot.mp4/) (video).

Comment: What is your hardware? Could you try another kernel (e.g. Slackware-current or Slackware-14.0)?

Comment: @peterph Macbook Pro Retina 13 Late 2013, multi-boot with rEFInd... how I try another kernel? is instead click on Enter type Slackware-current and then click on Enter... Or are you suggesting downloading older version of Slackware Linux?? Thanks

Comment: The latter - older version (e.g. `slackware64-14.0`) or the rolling version ("bleeding edge") `slackware64-current`. You may also want to check whether you could disable mouse in BIOS (UEFI, I suppose)